# How can I force a refresh of what ports have listeners

Tags: windows-xp, port, netstat, socket, pid

I'm trying to re-launch a WCF service that I killed earlier, but I'm getting an AddressAlreadyInUseException. The port it's attempting to use is 1819.

I ran netstat -nao from the command line, and have found there is a listening process on port 1819, that has a PID of 4840. I went into Process Explorer (from SysInternals) to try to kill PID 4840, but it's not there.

I'm guessing PID 4840 was the WCF service running earlier (that I killed) but it didn't clear out the listening port. How can I force WindowsXP to refresh the ports it thinks are being listened on?

Otherwise I'll have to reboot every time this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's a way to refresh it.  For now I have reconfigured the service to use another port until it's more convenient for me to restart.